# Where can I download Subversion binaries?

Tags: windows, svn

Where can I download Subversion 1.6.9 binaries for Windows (Apache 2.2-compatible, zipped, without a setup)?

Before Subversion moved to [Apache](http://subversion.apache.org/) they were available at [tigris.org](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100) (which is still referenced from the [download](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) page) but apparently that site/page is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find recent binaries for Windows in [CollabNet](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/)

Comment: Can you extract the binaries without running the setup?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw that you need without a setup. Anyway AFAIK you can directly extract the collabnet.exe file with a zip utility (I tested with 7zip) and extract the content in your preferred folder.

The difference will be that you'll not have any uninstaller.exe or registry changes, but the installer doesn't seems to be using the registry anyway.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Renaming the exe to zip worked. Thanks! Only svnmucc.exe appears to be missing.

Comment: You can also download compiled binaries from [here](https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx)
The come in .zip format so you can extract them freely.

Answer (score 0):

Apache's site hosts links to binaries now. http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Tigris is listed as one source, but the CollabNet mirror appears to have more recent versions.

Comment: Yes that is the link I posted as well. But I need the binaries zipped, not in a Setup.

Answer (score 0):

The [win32svn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn) has a zip tarball of the svn binaries for windows platforms.